# Retrieve all vertices from root vertex joined by edges with Gremlin query

Tags: json, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

How can I retrieve all vertex properties starting from the root vertex in Gremlin query?

We have the following structure:
Root Vertex: Employee

Edges: EdCompany, EdDepartment, EdRole
Vertices: Company, Department, Role

[image: graph example]

We are trying to receive the data of the other vertices joined with the root vertex.
Somethink like this:

```
{
    "employee": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "label": "Employee",
            "type": "vertex",
            "properties": { ... },
            "company": { 
                "id": "A220",
                "label": "Company",
                "type": "vertex",
                "properties": { ... }, 
            },
            "department": { ... },
            "edge": { ... }
        },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

We have tried that query but return a complex JSON:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Employee").inE().outV().tree()
```

EDIT:

We have also tried the query suggested by Kelvin:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Employee").inE().outV().tree().by(valueMap())
```

[image: last test image screen]

Stacktrace:
*Failure in submitting query: g.V().hasLabel("Employee").inE().outV().tree().by(valueMap()): Server serialization error: ActivityId : 29f4b64e-c476-44b8-8e35-a07dd31d4242 ExceptionType : GraphSerializeException ExceptionMessage : Gremlin Serialization Error: GraphSON V1_0 serializer cannot serialize object of type: MapField to a primitive value to perform the desired Gremlin step*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the tree from the root you can just add a `by(valueMap())` to your query to get the properties included as well. Such as:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Employee").
  inE().
  outV().
  tree().
    by(valueMap())
```

Comment: I have tried your query but it does not work. Check my edit please

Comment: It looks like you are using the GraphSON V1 serializer - please try with the V3 serializer or the GraphBinary serializer. It's not the query. It's the serializer being used.

Comment: I can not use V3 because Azure Cosmos DB + Gremlin support V1/V2 serializer only. What can I do in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what Cosmos does and does not support. You might try using just a single property key name as an experiment rather than `valueMap`. Have you tried the V2 serializer just in case? Does it support GraphBinary?

Comment: I’ll try with single property key however V2 and GraphBinary does not work. Thanks for the support